# Using "if" in this context

Tags: grammar

A sentence in Cambridge Dictionary:

> He is deluding himself **if** he thinks he is going to be promoted this year.

I'm not able to understand the meaning properly.

I'm aware of the uses of **if and whether** in **yes-no** questions in an indirect speech. But this sentence seems to be rather different.

What is the meaning of **if** in this context.

Thank you.

Comment: It has the same structure as: He is making a mistake if he thinks he knows everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can break this sentence up into a condition and a [hypothetical] result.
The sentence in question isn't indicating an indirect question, but rather **a condition.**

> *He is deluding himself* (result) **if he thinks he is going to be promoted this year.** (condition)

We can switch the order of these two parts:

> **If he thinks he is going to be promoted this year** (condition), *he is deluding himself.* (result)

The *if* is acting just like it does in these sentences:

> The show will be cancelled **if** it rains tomorrow.
>
> People will be upset **if** the highway is closed this weekend.

---

For reference, if you wish to know what the sentence means, it is that the person in question thinks that he will be promoted next year, but someone else (the speaker) thinks that the person is thinking the wrong thing (*deluding himself*), which may make him think he is better at his job than he really is.